# adding title labels inside faceted barplots

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, facet

I am creating a faceted barplots showing (each plot = different element, bars = region) and instead of having the title for each plot in the strip above I want to insert them in the actual plots. Each plot has a wildly different y-axis so I am struggling with how to define a consistent y position for the title label.
My code so far: I am thinking of using geom_text to add the labels?

```
    p1 <- ggplot(data = data, aes(region, concentration, fill = region)) + 
      geom_bar(stat="summary", fun = mean) +
      facet_wrap(~element,scales="free_y")+
      ylab("Element Concentration") +
      theme(strip.background = element_rect(fill=NA, color=NA),
            panel.background = element_rect(fill=NA, color="gray60"),
            panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
            panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
            panel.spacing.x=unit(0, "lines"),
            panel.spacing.y=unit(.3, "lines"),
            strip.text = element_blank(),
            axis.title.x=element_blank(),
            axis.text.x=element_blank(),
            axis.ticks.x=element_blank()) +
      scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 0)) + 
      scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0.3)))
```

[what I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWKCt.jpg)

[what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GydIu.jpg)

Additionally: if anyone is familiar with how to do the following for the y axis label that would be fantastic:
My y lab needs to say: "Element Concentration μg element/g Ca"
Really struggling with adding in the microgram portion of the axis title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be the `gggrid` package which similar to `ggplot2::annotation_custom` allows to place grobs on a ggplot using relative coordinates (and therefore works fine with different data range) but unlike `ggplot2::annotation_custom` allows for placing different grobs on each facet. To this end

1. write a custom function which takes two arguments (`data` and `coords`) and which creates the `textGrob`s
2. use `gggrid::grid_panel` to add the grobs to each facet or panel where we map `element` on e.g. the `label` aesthetic.

Using some fake random data:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(gggrid)
#> Loading required package: grid
library(grid)

title_label <- function(data, coords) {
  textGrob(unique(data$label),
    x = unit(.5, "npc"),
    y = unit(1, "npc") - unit(2, "mm"),
    vjust = 1,
    gp = gpar(fontsize = 10)
  )
}

ggplot(data = data, aes(region, concentration, fill = region)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "summary", fun = mean) +
  grid_panel(title_label, aes(label = element)) +
  facet_wrap(~element, scales = "free_y") +
  ylab("Element Concentration") +
  theme(
    strip.background = element_rect(fill = NA, color = NA),
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA, color = "gray60"),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.spacing.x = unit(0, "lines"),
    panel.spacing.y = unit(.3, "lines"),
    strip.text = element_blank(),
    axis.title.x = element_blank(),
    axis.text.x = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.x = element_blank()
  ) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0.3)))
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
set.seed(123)

data <- data.frame(
  region = sample(LETTERS[1:5], 100, replace = TRUE),
  concentration = unlist(lapply(1:5, function(x) runif(20, 0, 2 * x))),
  element = paste("element", 1:5)
)
```

Comment: I have to say, I'm not sure how this works but it did work! Thank you for your help!

Comment: @j-asano. (: yeah. Requires some effort to get into it. But as you see the effort to learn some grid or grob basics may be worthwhile for the additional flexibility when it comes to placing annotations on a plot.